# Can't parse this json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file that looks like:

```
[
{
  "host": "host1.com",
  "ip": "x.x.x.x",
  "port": 443,
  "tlsVersions": [
    "TLSv1_2"
  ],
  "cipherSuite": {
    "supported": [
      "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
    ]
  },
  "x509ChainDepth": 2,
  "verifyCertResult": true,
  "verifyHostResult": true,
  "ocspStapled": true,
  "verifyOcspResult": true,
  "certificateChain": [
  {
    "version": 3
  },  {
    "version": 3
  } ]
},

{
  "host": "host2.com",
  "ip": "y.y.y.y",
  "port": 443,
  "tlsVersions": [
    "TLSv1_2"
  ],
  "cipherSuite": {
    "supported": [
      "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
    ]
  },
  "x509ChainDepth": 2,
  "verifyCertResult": true,
  "verifyHostResult": true,
  "ocspStapled": true,
  "verifyOcspResult": true,
  "certificateChain": [
  {
    "version": 3
  },  {
    "version": 3
  } ]
}

]
```

I want to extract the `host` and `tlsVersions` for each host and print them in a line separated by comma. I want to loop over each host and print one `host` with its `tlsVersions` per line.

I tried this:

```
import json 

with open('result2.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

for distro in distros_dict:
    print(distro['host']+","+distro['tlsVersions']+'\n')
```

I get this error when I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 4, in <module>
    distros_dict = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What is the problem? The json library is installed and the import statement works without errors.

Comment: Is it valid JSON? If you give it to an online JSON validator or a command line tool or whatever, does it work? If not, Python won’t work either.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “The json library is installed”? Python 2.7 comes with a json module in the stdlib. Have you installed something else that hides this or something?

Comment: Yes. I did pip install json. I did not know that json is built-in.

Comment: Since you didn’t test your input, I copied and pasted it into an online validator, and it’s not valid JSON. So that’s your answer. What you do about it depends on a number of things you haven’t told us. How much control do you have over the code that generates this corrupt not-quite-JSON? If you can fix that, or get it fixed, that will be orders of magnitude easier and better than trying to parse garbage. If you can’t, then it depends on how much data you have to scan and/or code you can read to reverse engineer the garbage, how close to 100% your garbage-processing has to be, etc.

Comment: The main problem was with the format of your JSON. Please format it at  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com and replace all `+` used for concatenation in **print()**  with `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@user9371654**, there are 2 main problems associated with your `JSON file` and `Python code`.

- The contents of `result2.json` is not properly formatted.
- The parameters of `print()` function should be separated with `,` so replace all `+` used for concatenation with `,` ( If you still prefer `,` then uou will need to convert your list to string using `str()` to support concatenation).

> Copy your JSON content of `result2.json` and format it at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.

[image]

#### result2.json »

[image]

> **Note:** Update your JSON file `result2.json` with the following content.

```
[  
   {  
      "host":"host1.com",
      "ip":"x.x.x.x",
      "port":443,
      "tlsVersions":[  
         "TLSv1_2"
      ],
      "cipherSuite":{  
         "supported":[  
            "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
         ]
      },
      "x509ChainDepth":2,
      "verifyCertResult":true,
      "verifyHostResult":true,
      "ocspStapled":true,
      "verifyOcspResult":true,
      "certificateChain":[  
         {  
            "version":3
         },
         {  
            "version":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "host":"host2.com",
      "ip":"y.y.y.y",
      "port":443,
      "tlsVersions":[  
         "TLSv1_2"
      ],
      "cipherSuite":{  
         "supported":[  
            "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
         ]
      },
      "x509ChainDepth":2,
      "verifyCertResult":true,
      "verifyHostResult":true,
      "ocspStapled":true,
      "verifyOcspResult":true,
      "certificateChain":[  
         {  
            "version":3
         },
         {  
            "version":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### Python Code »

Finally try the below code:

```
import json 

with open('result2.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

for distro in distros_dict:
    print(distro['host'], "," , distro['tlsVersions'], '\n')
```

#### Output »

```
host1.com , ['TLSv1_2']

host2.com , ['TLSv1_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing commas on your objects. A lot of JSON parsers will struggle with this.

Rather than this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
}
```

You need something more like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the answer suggested regarding trailing commas, try this.

I think it's expecting the JSON data to contain an object, where you have an array.

What you have:

```
[ 
  { ... }, 
  { ... }
]
```

What I think it's expecting:

```
{
  "Items": [
    { ... }, 
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have an array at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `distro['tlsVersions']` is an array, not a string.

The following modification, by contrast, is valid, though it might not be what you actually want:

```
for distro in distros_dict:
    print(distro['host']+","+distro['tlsVersions'][0]+'\n')
```

The above produces:

```
host1.com,TLSv1_2

host2.com,TLSv1_2
```